# WPF ComboBox Showing ModelName rather than value after updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Models I am binding

```
namespace Project.Telematics_Plugin
{
    public class TelematicsEvent
    {
        public int  EventId { get;set; }

        public String MethodName { get; set; }

        public String Keyword { get;set; }

        public String Opcode { get;set; }

        public String Task { get;set; }

    }

    public class TelematicsKeyword
    {
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
    }

    public class TelematicsTask
    {
        public string Task { get;set; }
    }

    public class TelematicsOpcode
    {
        public string Opcode { get;set; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgMethods" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event Id" Width="70" Binding="{Binding EventId}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event Name" Width="300" Binding="{Binding MethodName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Keywords" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Keyword}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opcodes" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Opcode}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tasks" MinWidth="300">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Task}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Task}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Task" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Task, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I am running the Code as shown above and try to edit some column from dropdown as shown below
[image]

after selecting value of dropdown it shows back model name with full namespace in grid rather than value of combobox selected item.
[image]

I am not using MVVM , just writing code in WinForm style.
here is my code behind class xaml.cs

```
public AddInScreen()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Tasks = new List<TelematicsTask>();
    Keywords = new List<TelematicsKeyword>();
    Opcodes = new List<TelematicsOpcode>();
    Events = new List<TelematicsEvent>();


    Tasks.Add(new TelematicsTask() { Task = "ApplicationStarted" });
    Tasks.Add(new TelematicsTask() { Task = "ApplicationClosed" });
    Tasks.Add(new TelematicsTask() { Task = "ApplicationError" });


    Keywords.Add(new TelematicsKeyword() { Keyword = "Application" });
    Keywords.Add(new TelematicsKeyword() { Keyword = "DataAccess" });
    Keywords.Add(new TelematicsKeyword() { Keyword = "UserInterface" });
    Keywords.Add(new TelematicsKeyword() { Keyword = "Session" });

    Opcodes.Add(new TelematicsOpcode() { Opcode = "Start" });
    Opcodes.Add(new TelematicsOpcode() { Opcode = "Finish" });
    Opcodes.Add(new TelematicsOpcode() { Opcode = "Error" });
    Opcodes.Add(new TelematicsOpcode() { Opcode = "Closed" });

    Events.Add(new TelematicsEvent() { EventId = 100, MethodName = "ApplicationStarted", Task= "ApplicationStarted", Keyword = "Application", Opcode = "Start" });
    Events.Add(new TelematicsEvent() { EventId = 100, MethodName = "ApplicationClosed",Task= "ApplicationClosed", Keyword = "Application", Opcode = "Closed" });
    Events.Add(new TelematicsEvent() { EventId = 100, MethodName = "ApplicationError",Task= "ApplicationError", Keyword = "Application", Opcode = "Error" });

    grdTasks.Items.Clear();
    grdKeywords.Items.Clear();
    grdOpcodes.Items.Clear();

    grdTasks.ItemsSource = Tasks;
    grdOpcodes.ItemsSource = Opcodes;
    grdKeywords.ItemsSource = Keywords;
    dgMethods.ItemsSource = Events;

    this.DataContext = Tasks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with

`SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Task, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`.

You don't have property of type `TelematicsTask` in your `TelematicsEvent` class. And items in your combobox are of type `TelematicsTask` and when you are binding the selected item i.e `TelematicsTask` instance to the string it is setting value by calling `ToString()` on it. Remove the `SelectedItem` binding and it will be fine.

Comment: after removing SelectedItem binding , now when I am updating drowndown selected item manually it is not updating on DataGridCell.. What is the best way to update that TextBlock Template with selected ComboBox value..